# Handle notifications with app killed IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

right now I'm developing an app capable of receiving notifications, and it was going fine, until I stepped on the need of having to send to my  server a copy of the notification received on the app.

Although I know the downsides to this approach, it's the only way that I can process the notifications received.

Right now I can handle the notifications that are received with the app on background and foreground through this method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

. Inside this method I call the  NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest to send to my server the notification data received.

But when the app is killed (eliminated from the the background apps), I no longer can process the notification through this method.

Is there a method that I can call when the app is killed that allows me to make a post request to my server after I receive the notification?

Comment: If you want to know just that it delivered to the device you can do that with APNS. Not sure how but o remember Parse telling you want devices (by token) had received the push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to do this until and unless you open the App...

Comment: I'm starting to get the same feeling ... I know that my approach is not the best one, but it sucks that on android its possible to do this, but not on ios. I guess I have to start thinking in other approaches to the problem... :/

Comment: yes thats the case unfortunately, it depends on your requirement, if you just to the let the server know that user get the notification you can create the API and hit it on every launch of app to receive any change that the server sent it in Push notification.